# How can I select paragraphs easier in iOS 7?

Tags: ios

Selecting text has become very clunky in iOS 7, whereas it was very smooth in previous operating systems. In particular, in iOS 6, three taps of some text would select the whole paragraph. This appears to have stopped working in iOS 7.

Is there a way to select a whole paragraph by tapping the screen in iOS 7?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, you can't triple tap to select a paragraph. Here's what I do, however, to select larger chunks of text.

Double-tap and hold your finger puts iOS 7 into "drag to select" mode.

1. Double-tap and hold your finger on the first word of the paragraph
2. Drag down to select

Comment: What you describe only works if the cursor is not already placed on the screen and I feel its a bit of a workaround

Answer (score 0):

A two-finger single tap will select a stand alone sentence or a complete paragraph when in  edit mode.